# Regular Expression for Benchmark calculations in Python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression to capture Latency of Size 1 (i.e. 1.15). I am using the following regular expression: (?!1\s+)([\d.]+)

```
# OSU MPI Latency Test v4.4.1
# Size          Latency (us)
0                       1.11
1                       1.15
2                       1.14
4                       1.14
8                       1.14
16                      1.16
32                      1.18
64                      1.22
128                     1.31
256                     1.83
512                     1.95
1024                    2.28
2048                    2.79
4096                    3.20
8192                    4.53
16384                   6.96
32768                  10.17
65536                  15.63
131072                 26.01
262144                 46.70
524288                 88.15
1048576               171.87
2097152               339.42
4194304               668.69
```

I am expecting to get 306 values but end up with 293. I am not sure if my regular expression is written incorrectly. The size of the text file is huge (306 tables similar to above) and hence I am trying to find a simpler way of improving this.

Comment: Why are you using negative look-ahead?

Comment: What is the purpose of the `1` in your pattern  `(?!1\s+)`?

Comment: I am only trying to get the latency value for 1 (i.e. 1.15)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually your regex is capturing everything but `1` which is weird.

For grabbing latency for `1` only, you can use:

```
^1\s+([\d.]+)$
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/eJ8dR9/1)**

[image]